# File upload does not always work in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am using the AngularJS file upload from (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) and it does not consistently work for the same file over and over.  Not sure it is in the AngularJS code or my REST API code.

My controller code -

```
[Route("uploadFile")]
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFile()
{
    var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
    var folderExists = Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"));
    if (!folderExists)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"));
    if (httpPostedFile != null)
    {
        var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"), httpPostedFile.FileName);
        httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    }
}
```

My AngularJS controller -

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: apiUrl.serviceBase + "api/quotes/uploadFile"
});
uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem) {
    $scope.uploader.queue = [];
    $scope.uploader.progress = 0;
    alert("Selected file has been uploaded successfully.");
    vm.file.fileName = fileItem.file.name;
    vm.file.originatedBy = vm.userName;
    vm.file.modifiedBy = vm.userName;
    vm.file.rfq = vm.rfq;
    quotesService.updateFile(vm.file).then(processSuccess, processError);
    $location.path("/quotes");
};

uploader.onErrorItem = function () {
    alert("We were unable to upload your file. Please try again.");
};
```

My HTML code -

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                        <td><strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong></td>
                        <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                        <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                            <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                            <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                            <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                        </td>
                        <td nowrap>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am not sure where the error is, sometimes it never gets to the REST API.  The way that I am testing is trying to load the same file over and over again.  Do I have to do something after I call the saveas function?

Comment: Not clear. What do you want exactly? 1. File uploads, but you don't know what to do then? File does not upload? And 3. Why you are not returning URL for saved file `public void UploadFile()`? (_that should return URL for uploaded file imo_)

Comment: The file needs to be saved in a directory on the IIS server.  It works the first time I upload the file, but not anytime there after.  I don't  need the URL of the saved file.

Comment: I don't deal with asp at all but sure sounds like you need to configure the save to allow overwrite of existing file or have it change file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This suggestion is too long for comment*

This is source of HttpPostFile class located [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpPostedFile.cs,e79644a761deb1a0)

```
public void SaveAs(String filename) {
            // VSWhidbey 82855
            if (!Path.IsPathRooted(filename)) {
                HttpRuntimeSection config = RuntimeConfig.GetConfig().HttpRuntime;
                if (config.RequireRootedSaveAsPath) {
                    throw new HttpException(SR.GetString(SR.SaveAs_requires_rooted_path, filename));
                }
            }

            FileStream f = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

            try {
                _stream.WriteTo(f);
                f.Flush();
            }
            finally {
                f.Close();
            }
        }
```

`FileMode.Create` - Creates a new file. If the file already exists, it is overwritten.

So basically try to use FileStream yourself, because `HttpPostFile` strangely doesn't have exception catcher/thrower

```
[Route("uploadFile")]
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFile()
{
    try {
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
        var folderExists = Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"));
        if (!folderExists) Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"));
        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments"), httpPostedFile.FileName);
            HttpInputStream _stream = new HttpInputStream();
            FileStream f = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create);

            _stream.WriteTo(f);
            f.Flush();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw e;       
        }
        finally {
            f.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: i'm on mac, and couldn't check that code above, so please be aware</sup>